# what does "vcore-seconds" in hadoop job log mean?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

```
Job Counters
    Launched map tasks=3
    Launched reduce tasks=45
    Data-local map tasks=1
    Rack-local map tasks=2
    Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=29338
    Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=200225
    Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=29338
    Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=200225
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=29338
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=200225
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=30042112
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=205030400
```

what does "vcore-seconds" mean and what is the difference between "vcore-seconds " and "Total time spent"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a official documentation about this metrics, but if I understand fine ([see here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationResourceUsageReport.html#getVcoreSeconds())), vcore-seconds is the sum of seconds in which Hadoop allocate vcore for some task.

I think this metric show how much time spend your MapReduce application in Map and Reduce phases, without involved other tasks (Scheduled task, shuffle and sort intermediate keys, etc...)

Comment: helpful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty obvious that vcore-seconds is actually in milliseconds if you look at the job counters above; the output explicitly states that the unit is '(ms)' for the "Total time spent" lines but omits that explicit unit in the lines regarding vcore-seconds and megabyte-seconds, but it's clear that one vcore was being used in that example and yet the mapping vcore-seconds is shown as 29338 instead of 29.338 !

I've verified this "clarity defect" by testing many actual jobs and it's consistently present.

I've ransacked cloudera's documentation and am shocked to find that they never document the fact that vcore-seconds should have been named vcore-ms !